# Why are the same comments showing up on multiple pages in AngularJs 1.5

Tags: angularjs, disqus

I've tried the following code on different pages like `about, services` with appropriate `URL` and `identifier`. But I get the same comments on both pages. I'm using Angular 1.5. I've added this to the corresponding controller.

```js
        var disqus_config = function () {
            // About us
            this.page.url = "http://localhost/#!/about";  
            this.page.identifier = "about"; 
            // For Services Page
            //this.page.url = "http://localhost/#!/services"; 
            //this.page.identifier = "services"; 
        };

        (function() { // DON'T EDIT BELOW THIS LINE
            var d = document, s = d.createElement('script');
            s.src = 'https://smetest.disqus.com/embed.js';
            s.setAttribute('data-timestamp', +new Date());
            (d.head || d.body).appendChild(s);
        })();
```

Can anyone help with this?

Comment: Does it support SPA? Your different pages in angular are one page in normal world.

Comment: @Petr Yes It supports SPA. But the same comments are displaying both pages. I've reloaded after contentloaded event fires using DISQUS.reset. But When I navigate to another page I got this msg(Use DISQUS.reset instead of reloading embed.js please.) on console.log.